# Strange load instructions produced by mipsel-gcc when compiling glibc

Tags: c, assembly, mips, glibc, gem5

I'm trying to get a small piece of hello-world MIPS program running in Gem 5 simulator. The program was compiled with gcc 4.9.2 and glibc 2.19 (built by crosstool-ng) and runs well in qemu, but it crashed with a page fault (trying to access address 0) in gem5.

Code is rather simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`file ./test` result:

> ./test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1, statically
>   linked, for GNU/Linux 3.15.4, not stripped

After some debugging with gdb, I figured out that the page fault is triggered by `_dl_setup_stack_chk_guard` function in glibc. It accepts a void pointer called `_dl_random` passed by `__libc_start_main` function, which happens to be `NULL`. However, as far as I know, these functions never dereference the pointer, but instructions were generated to load values from the memory `_dl_random` pointer points to. Some code pieces might help understanding:

in function `__libc_start_main` (macro `THREAD_SET_STACK_GUARD` is not set):

```
   /* Initialize the thread library at least a bit since the libgcc
   functions are using thread functions if these are available and
   we need to setup errno.  */
  __pthread_initialize_minimal ();

  /* Set up the stack checker's canary.  */
  uintptr_t stack_chk_guard = _dl_setup_stack_chk_guard (_dl_random);
# ifdef THREAD_SET_STACK_GUARD
  THREAD_SET_STACK_GUARD (stack_chk_guard);
# else
  __stack_chk_guard = stack_chk_guard;
# endif
```

in function `_dl_setup_stack_chk_guard` (always inlined):

```
static inline uintptr_t __attribute__ ((always_inline))
_dl_setup_stack_chk_guard (void *dl_random)
{
  union
  {
    uintptr_t num;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof (uintptr_t)];
  } ret = { 0 };

  if (dl_random == NULL)
    {
      ret.bytes[sizeof (ret) - 1] = 255;
      ret.bytes[sizeof (ret) - 2] = '\n';
    }
  else
    {
      memcpy (ret.bytes, dl_random, sizeof (ret));
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
      ret.num &= ~(uintptr_t) 0xff;
#elif BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
      ret.num &= ~((uintptr_t) 0xff << (8 * (sizeof (ret) - 1)));
#else
# error "BYTE_ORDER unknown"
#endif
    }
  return ret.num;
}
```

disassembly code:

```
   0x00400ea4 <+228>:   jal 0x4014b4 <__pthread_initialize_minimal>
   0x00400ea8 <+232>:   nop
   0x00400eac <+236>:   lui v0,0x4a
   0x00400eb0 <+240>:   lw  v0,6232(v0)
   0x00400eb4 <+244>:   li  a0,-256
   0x00400eb8 <+248>:   lwl v1,3(v0)
   0x00400ebc <+252>:   lwr v1,0(v0)
   0x00400ec0 <+256>:   addiu   v0,v0,4
   0x00400ec4 <+260>:   and v1,v1,a0
   0x00400ec8 <+264>:   lui a0,0x4a
   0x00400ecc <+268>:   sw  v1,6228(a0)
```

- `0x4a1858 (0x4a0000 + 6232)` is the address of `_dl_random`
- `0x4a1854 (0x4a0000 + 6228)` is the address of `__stack_chk_guard`

Page fault occurs at `0x00400eb8`. I don't quite get it how instruction `0x00400eb8` and `0x00400ebc` are generated. Could someone shed some light on it please? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the compiler thinks `dl_random` can not be `NULL`. Verify the source of `_dl_random`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your reply. Here is the declaration of `_dl_random`: `extern void *_dl_random attribute_hidden attribute_relro`. Digging further I realized that `attribute_relro` actually refers to `__attribute__ ((section (".data.rel.ro")))`.  Could it mean the compiler is certain that `_dl_random` is pointed to data section?

Comment: That just means the `_dl_random` itself is in the `.data.rel.ro` section, it says nothing about what it's points to. It's not all clear why the compiler  would assume it's not NULL.

Comment: @Jester@Ross Ridge Sorry I made a foolish mistake... The copy of `_dl_setup_stack_chk_guard` I gave in description does not involve in compilation at all. However, there is another version located in a different directory I've missed. Most implementations are the same, except that if statement is enclosed with a ifndef, whose macro, `__ASSUME_AT_RANDOM`, is a default-enabled kernel feature. Therefore, if statement was skipped and it also explains why there is an `and` instruction. Perhaps I should file a bug report complaining gem5 does not set the value. Thanks again for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I find the root of this problem and my suggestion for solution.

I think it helpful to dive into [the Glibc source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/csu/libc-start.c.html#126) to see what really happens. Starting from `_dl_random` or `__libc_start_main` are both OK.

As the value of `_dl_random` is unexpectedly NULL, we need to find how this variable initialize and [where it is assigned](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/elf/dl-support.c.html#291). With the help of code analysing tools, we can find `_dl_random` in Glibc is only assigned with meaningful value in function [`_dl_aux_init`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/elf/dl-support.c.html#_dl_aux_init), and this function is called by `__libc_start_min`.

`_dl_aux_init` iterates on its parameter -- `auxvec` -- and acts corresponding to `auxvec[i].at_type`. `AT_RANDOM` is the case for the assignment of `_dl_random`. So the problem is that there isn't an `AT_RANDOM` element to make `_dl_random` assigned.

As the program runs well in user mode qemu, the root of this problem resides in system environment provider, say, gem5, which has the responsibility to construct `auxvec`. Having that keyword, we can find that the `auxv` is constructed in `gem5/src/arch/<arch-name>/process.cc`.

The current `auxv` for MIPS is constructed as below:

```
    // Set the system page size
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_PAGESZ, MipsISA::PageBytes));
    // Set the frequency at which time() increments
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_CLKTCK, 100));
    // For statically linked executables, this is the virtual
    // address of the program header tables if they appear in the
    // executable image.
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_PHDR, elfObject->programHeaderTable()));
    DPRINTF(Loader, "auxv at PHDR %08p\n", elfObject->programHeaderTable());
    // This is the size of a program header entry from the elf file.
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_PHENT, elfObject->programHeaderSize()));
    // This is the number of program headers from the original elf file.
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_PHNUM, elfObject->programHeaderCount()));
    //The entry point to the program
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_ENTRY, objFile->entryPoint()));
    //Different user and group IDs
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_UID, uid()));
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_EUID, euid()));
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_GID, gid()));
    auxv.push_back(auxv_t(M5_AT_EGID, egid()));
```

Now we know what to do. We just need to provide an accessible address value to `_dl_random` tagged by `MT_AT_RANDOM`. Gem5's ARM arch implements this already ([code](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/master/src/arch/arm/process.cc#L215)). Maybe we can take it as an example.